# How to solve 'Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.' flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to use any flutter command this comes. (Inside a directory or outside a directory )

```
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled flutter and it just worked for me